# D3.js Display raster and vector

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to modify Mike Bostock's sample (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5914438) that overlays a vector topojson on OpenStreetMap.  Is it possible to modify this sample using Google Map instead of OpenStreetMap?

The following loads the Google map:

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.68551, -96.503906),       
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE                     
    });
    map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'default' });
}
```

I have a d3.js version 3 that loads the geojson file over Google map. But now I need some animation functionalities found only in d3.js version 4 and my d3.js v3 codes don't work.  Below is my d3.js version 3 codes:

```
function drawConusCounties() {        
    var cntyPath = "/geo/conus_counties.json";

    d3.json(cntyPath, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        $(function () {
            var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

            overlay.onAdd = function () {
                var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
                    .attr("class", "cnty");

                var svg = layer.append("svg");
                var cnty = svg.append("g").attr("class", "cnty");

                overlay.draw = function () {
                    var markerOverlay = this;
                    var overlayProjection = markerOverlay.getProjection();

                    // Turn the overlay projection into a d3 projection
                    var googleMapProjection = function (coordinates) {
                        var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0]);
                        var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
                        return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y + 4000];
                    }

                    path = d3.geo.path().projection(googleMapProjection);

                    cnty.selectAll("path")
                        .data(d3.entries(data)[1].value)
                        .attr("d", path) // update existing paths
                    .enter()
                        .append("svg:path")
                        .attr("class", "cnty5")
                        .attr("cntyname", function (d, i) {
                            return d3.entries(data)[1].value[i].properties.NAME;
                        })
                        .attr("d", path);
                }; //end overlay draw
            }; //end onAdd

            overlay.setMap(map);
        }); //end function call

    }); //end d3 call
}
```

Comment: What animation features do you need from v4 that do not exist in v3?

Comment: I was able to overlay the geojson data by creating an <svg> tag inside the <map> tag and then calling the function, drawConusCounties() inside the initMap() function. This seems to solve the problem:
    <div id=map>
        <svg id="SvgOverlay">
            <defs>
                <filter id="blur">
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <g transform="translate(50,450)"></g>
    </svg>
</div>

Not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: I still need to do the animation. How do I post additional codes for this thread in Stack Overflow? So easy to do it in Microsoft's forum.  I'm lost here.

Comment: You should be able to edit the question - at the bottom of the question, just above these comments there are  few text links - one is to edit, you can add additional code and information from there

Comment: My animation consists of data collected for field conditions (runoff, moisture, etc.) on a 3-day interval for the continental US. So I want to start the animation when a user selects the field condition from a dropdownlist.

Comment: For a sample of what I'm trying to do, see:  http://realtimeceap.brc.tamus.edu/Home/SurfaceRunoff
Only this time, I want to use Google map as a background.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I'm using d3.js version 3 to do an overlay to Google map. I think some overlay function names are changed in version 4 and I'll need to research those. However, I'm able to overlay by simply calling the overlay function within the initMap() function as follows:

```
function initMap() {
    $('#SvgOverlay').hide();

    map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.68551, -96.503906),       
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE                     
    });
    map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'default' });

    drawConusCounties();
} //end function call
```